# Adding email list as registered users

Tags: user-registration, email

I collected some emails via Mailpoet plugin. Now I need to create for each email a registered user.

The best UX I'm thinking about is automatically creating a user with a one-time password that needs to be changed after the first access.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: That's how the admin site create user already works. You can just hook into that, or copy the code from there?

Answer (score -1):

With this plugin, you could add users from CSV file:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/

You could use your mail list CSV and import it.